# Event listener not attached to first element

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I've loaded bunch of configs and want to generate checkboxes based on loaded configs. The problem i'm having is that the first element does not get event handler attached to it, while others do. Any thoughts?

```
let selectedProducts = [];
function addToSelector(name,key){
    let selectorCode = `<div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="${key}" id="${key}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="${key}">${name}</label>
                        </div>`;
    let productElem = document.getElementById("products");
    productElem.innerHTML += selectorCode;
    let checkboxElem = document.getElementById(key);
    log(checkboxElem);
    checkboxElem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        log(`Click on checkbox: ${key} with a name ${name}`);
        let target = e.target;
        if (target.checked){
            selectedProducts.push(key);
        }
        else {
            selectedProducts = selectedProducts.splice(selectedProducts.indexOf(key), 1);
        }
        
    });
}
```

Log reveals two created elements:
[image: log]

Event handlers for both:
[image: not working event hanlder]
[image: working event handler]

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code? the element with id `products`. Also please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This line: `productElem.innerHTML += selectorCode;` wipes all the previously attached event listeners from the elements inside `productElem`. Setting `innerHTML` creates new elements, use [insertAdjacenHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead.